# Are there other Game Boy replicas than the Analogue Pocket that can run Game Boy cartridges?

Tags: game-boy, game-cartridge

The [Analogue Pocket](https://www.analogue.co/pocket) can run Game Boy Cartridges. Are there any other, currently-available, clones that can do this?

(The on-topic nature of this question was discussed on [Is asking for the existence of a device equal to a buying recommendation?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1147/79))

Comment: What aspect of the Pocket specifically are you looking for? You can get a game boy emulator for basically any computer these days.

Comment: @Raffzahn What is the right sites to ask this?

Comment: @somega I don’t think they are all that welcome on *any* Stack Exchange site. Compare <https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/168/15334>.

Comment: @user3840170 But I didn't ask for a buying recommandation. I asked for the existance.

Comment: I agree it’s not exactly the same, but the question you want to ask would not be a very good fit for the site for much of the same reasons as a more typical recommendation question would not be. (I had the idea of asking a question like that myself once, for what it’s worth.)

Comment: It's sad it's not possible to ask such a question on SE at all.

Comment: @somega Don't be discouraged, it's not a good fit for SE because the answer changes over time but you got an answer. I think a lot of people were interested in your question, that's why it wasn't closed immediately.

Comment: Beside sounding like a what to buy question, it's as well asking for a list answer, which as well is explicit off topic.

Answer (score 9):

Game Boy clones, defined as handhelds that clone the function of the Game Boy (specifically original cartridge compatibility) and not just the form of it (i.e. Game King / Mega Duck / block game SoCs ), have been around almost since the Game Boy itself came out.

They've increased in sophistication from the 90s to the present from being LCD gadgets like the GB itself to being in colour, backlit, FPGA-based and so on, and as you've found they're still in production in things like the Pocket.

The oldest one I can find that most closely resembles the Game Boy in technological level is the [**Game Fighter**](https://blog.gg8.se/wordpress/2012/11/11/gameboy-clone-game-fighter-teardown/) aka Crazy Boy.

Some later examples include the **Super Beautiful** aka Super Thunderbolt, **KF2000**, **GB Boy Color**, **Revo K101**, **Bittboy**, **Exeq GameBox GBADVANCE**.

Comment: (a bit far afield, but the Mega Duck is an interesting case of a "just the form" clone, as it actually uses the same CPU as the original Game Boy, has the same display size and resolution, and arguably a slightly *better* graphics controller... but it's still not game-compatible in any way.)

Comment: @knol The revo k 101 cannot read cartridges. I think the only one still buyable (of those you listed) is the GB boy color.

Comment: Hmm, I'm reading that the k 101 can play GBA carts, so it can't do original GB? Or are these articles talking about the k 101 plus?

Comment: @knol There is only the k101 plus (no other k101) and it cannot read cartridges.

Comment: @hobbs It is actually almost the exact same as a regular GB, just some of the IO registers have been shuffled around to artificially make stock GB games not compatible. You can assemble GB games from source for the MD just by changing some constants.